# Angular 2 ngOnChanges not firing when setting value via component reference

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, ngonchanges

I'm creating a component dynamically this way:

```
let componentFactory = this._componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.component);
this.componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
this.componentRef.instance.text = this.text;
```

As you see I also assign a value to the "text" property. That work's, but it doesn't fire the ngOnChanges in the target component and therefore also doesn't trigger change detection (I'm on "Push" strategy).

I tried to manually trigger it with

```
this.componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
```

and

```
this.componentRef.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
```

but without success.

Any ideas how I can assign the new text value to the target components @Input('text') in a better way? Text is just a String value.

**UPDATE:**
I have now build a work around with a setter in the target component:

```
@Input('text')
set text(text: string) {
    this._text = text;
    this.cdRef.markForCheck();
}
```

It works but that's a bit hacky, I would still prefer a more "angular" way.

Comment: is it really working? I don't think it works ! Could you please provide a working link if you have?